# Why is Dolge not a Christian name?

Tags: expressions, names, charles-dickens

(Note: This might be better suited for a different stack site, but since literature closed, I thought this was the closest related site).

I've recently been re-reading Great Expectations, and, in chapter 15, Pip introduces Dolge Orlick:

> Now, Joe kept a journeyman at weekly wages whose name was Orlick. He pretended that his Christian name was Dolge - a clear impossibility - but he was a fellow of that obstinate disposition that I believe him to have been the prey of no delusion in this particular, but willfully to have imposed that name upon the village as an affront to its understanding.

I'm wondering why it's obvious that Dolge couldn't be a Christian name. Is this something about Victorian English that I'm missing?

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with English; maybe Victorian customs. I think the idea is that no sane parent would name their child Dolge. And if a priest had to approve the name, this could have indeed been an impossibility.

Comment: Dickens chose his names very carefully so they would say something about the character. Both Dolge and Orlick suggest some dirtiness and uncivilized habits.

Comment: Completely unrelated: 

I just stumbled on your question here because I'm trying to do research on a man named Christian Dolge (he was the father of Alfred Dolge, a "benevolent" industrialist of the late 19th-century). Christian Dolge was a piano maker in Saxony who was sentenced to death for playing a part in the 1848 uprisings. That being said, I doubt Dickens had heard of him, and none of this has any bearing on Dolge as a first name.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My post-mortem mind-reading capability does not, inexplicably, include Charles Dickens, so as to the word-play involved here @user103188 makes some valuable observations that I won't be able to top.  But just in case you were wondering, it is a clear impossibility that "Dolge" is a Christian name, because it isn't Samuel, George, William, or any of a large but finite number of names recognized in English as what we call "first names".  At least at the time of Mr. Dickens.

And in light of Peter Shor's comment, I should expand this a bit.

A person's "Christian" name in Dickens' time was the name given to him or her at baptism in whatever Christian church he or she was christened into.  No parish priest would have gone along with naming an infant "Dolge" at baptism (because the name doesn't appear in the Bible or is otherwise recognized as "Christian").  I haven't done an in-depth examination of all the baptismal records of Victorian England, but I seriously doubt that any names other than those of great conventionality would be found therein.

But anyone could choose whatever nickname he or she wanted to use -- as long as he or she could get others to go along with it, anyway. "Mxyzptlk", for example.  Mr. Orlick, however, is claiming that his "Christian" name is "Dolge".  Which as the narrator in the tale is pointing out, is clearly impossible.

Incidentally, I have an ancestor whose birth name was Toom-ya-nem, but who for convenience in dealing with Whites later took the "Christian" name "Joseph".

Comment: In the time of Mr. Dickens, people had all sorts of "first names" which were unconventional. I don't believe there was a finite list of permissible names the way there is in some countries.

Comment: @PeterShor, I beg to differ, of course. There *had* to be a finite list of permissible first names. People just didn't have a baby and then approach the parish clergy for baptism and claim the child's name would be "Mxyzptlk". That being said, "Tim" isn't a Christian name, but "Timothy" is.  You could claim anything at all as a nickname, and people did, but to claim your "Christian" name (i.e. the name you were given at baptism in Dickens' time) is "Dolge" is clearly impossible.  He wasn't claiming it was his nickname, which is clearly possible, but he was claiming it as his "Christian" name.

Comment: it could have been (and I strongly suspect it was) left entirely to the parish priest's discretion. "Mxyzptick" would never have been accepted, but I don't see why "Tim" couldn't have been. There are lots of real first names in the Victorian era which do not appear in the Bible, for example "Hilary" and "Graham".

Comment: I won't try to argue with you over Hilary or Graham, but Dolge is clearly not a name the character could have been awarded as a "Christian" name, at least not normally.  That's all I am trying to say.  Dickens' narrator is trying to say that the character took the name just to be cantankerous, and that claiming the name was his baptismal name was "impossible".  Even if it really had happened that way.

Comment: How sure can we be that by Christian name Dickens means baptismal name rather than simply first name? Was a baptismal name a first name only, or did it consist of two ot more names? Also @Peter Shor.

Comment: @CarSmack: Do you have an evidence that there a difference between baptismal name and first (and middle) name in England in the 19th century? And if there had been a finite list of approved first names, I very much doubt that ["Chichester"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chichester_Parkinson-Fortescue,_1st_Baron_Carlingford) would have been on it.

Comment: @CarSmack there is a reason why they call the name by which a person is "christened" a Christian name.  Someone of Jewish faith would not have a Christian name for that very reason, even if a nominally Christian name (such as Abraham) were chosen.  They were a significantly more religious society back then.  Nowadays we couldn't care less, but back then?  They fought WARS over religious faith.  <Shudder>  And I say this as a very religious person.  And it meant *first* name only.  Surnames could be changed legally, but as far as I am aware, you were stuck with your Christian name.

Comment: @PeterShor I do not have evidence. I am asking how sure we can be. And, by the way, on what do you base 'people had all sorts of "first names" which were unconventional' and 'There are lots of real first names in the Victorian era which do not appear in the Bible, for example "Hilary" and "Graham".' I mean, were you referencing a list or something?

Comment: Francis was a popular Christian name (in the sense of the name under which someone was baptised) at various times in the past, but it is not found in the Bible and is based on a nickname given to St Francis of Assisi. It's invented nature didn't prevent people from being baptised under it. Parish registers show a variety of names though not the same indiscriminate variety we see now. Also Dolge was a surname that would have been known to Dickens I suspect.

Comment: The whole point of this, @FrancisDavey, is that a "Christian" name in the Victorian era was a name under which one would be "christened". These were frequently biblical names, but often were not.  "Victoria" was not biblical, either, yet this was her "Christian" name because that was the name she was baptized or christened with.  "Dolge", as indicated by Dickens' narrator, was an invented name and as such clearly not a "Christian" name.  I suppose I should add, "In his humble opinion."  <Sigh> Can we dispense with trivial dispute over this? I think I have given the same answer 10 times by now.

Comment: Besides, Mxyzptlk is a surname anyway. In _Smallville_, the heterodyne hypnotist's "Christian name" is Mikhail, after the archangel.

Comment: I once knew an Italian old priest who refused to baptize a baby girl, Greta, because a "Saint Greta" didn't exist (at least that was the explanation I heard at the time, ca 25 years ago, before anyone could check online.) So I think the criteria used in Victorian England  isn't necessarily that a Christian name had to be found in the Bible, as long as there was a saint with the same name, it was "acceptable". E.g. Hilary is derived from Ilaria, and that is a saint's name. Apparently there are 10,000 saints, so no shortage of "Christian names" to choose from.

Comment: @Cyberherbalist Dolge was a *surname*. Census records reveal a reasonable number of Dolges in the UK in the 19th century. Arthur Dolge hadn't achieved fame by the time of Dickens's writing so it may be that he didn't know about it, but it isn't impossible that he knew of it as a surname (maybe subconsiously) which is why he rejected it as a Christian name. The point about Francis is that there was continuous innovation in Baptismal names even in the Mediaeval period. Victorian priests were not anything like as rigid as you suppose.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yes, that's it. When you receive a name during the baptism, it is supposed to be a name of a known saint/martyr/biblical person; you are basically making an "association" with someone which is supposed to be the "helper", "spiritual ancestor" (or however you want to call it) for the person getting baptized. In fact in the old days the [name day](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_day) was more important than birthday because 1) often birthday wasn't even recorded at all (for non-nobles) and 2) the important day was the day when you were "born a Christian" and "devoted" to the saint

Comment: @Mari-LouA However, I don't think that there is any formal *requirement* about this. Surely a priest probably wont be happy to baptize someone with a vulgar/profane name, but Greta doesn't seem to fall under this class. In fact Greta is an [hypocorism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypocorism) of Margherita, so I'd argue that there *is* a saint "of reference" for such name.

Comment: @Bakuriu the parents simply chose to baptize their child in a different church. Greta is not an Italian diminutive for Margherita, so I imagine the elderly priest considered it "foreign", but certainly there was no suggestion of it being nonsensical or vulgar. Nice links btw, thanks :)

Comment: @Bakuriu The priest who baptised me certainly didn’t seem to have an issue with the fact that my name is not only not carried by any saints or Christian figures, but is indeed the name of a _pagan_ (Roman) deity. Even [back in the 14th century](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Janus_of_Cyprus), it seems to have been accepted by priests.

Comment: In England, there was little restriction on  baptismal name so long as they were not offensive or fraudulent.  One real Victorian example I know involved accidental confusion over Christian names and surnames, leading to someone being called [James Duff Duff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Duff_Duff)

Answer (score 4):

The [point](http://www.johndclare.net/English/Dickens_3_names.htm) is made by Charles Dickens in *Great Expectations*, (ch. 17). It is a 'pretended Christian name' invented merely 'to affront mankind'.

In this novel wordplay is supremely important, so you have to imagine Dickens hearing Orlick pronouncing this nonsense name with a Kentish-Cockney intonation: with jutting jaw, puffed resentful cheeks, the sullen youth says something like 'Dodge', 'Forge', 'George'. After all, Estella, in chapter 8, is happy to say that the name Satis is 'Greek, or Latin, or Hebrew, or all three'.

Comment: If you're going to give interesting answers like this, and you plan to stick around, you might as well pick a "real" user name! :-)

Comment: I accepted @Cyberherbalist's answer, just because I think it more clearly addressed the question I was asking. However, I really do appreciate this answer, as well, so I +1'ed it.

Comment: Is @Cyberherbalist any better or more "real" a user name than user103188 is? What are the pros and cons of staying with user103188? After all if user103188 sticks around awhile  the name is quite recognizable. Must someone who gives interesting answers conform to another user's opinion regarding user names?

Comment: @CarSmack It's not particularly recognisable, no. Especially not if one of user103188's answers appears right next to answers by user103271 and user101936, for example. Why do we give our children names instead of just calling them _Child 7,327,839,312_ (etc.)? Same reason.

Comment: There are several user#### names on SE that I find particularly recognizable simply based on the characteristics of their answer. Or simply by seeing such a username on a repetitive basis. I don't know, we used to memorize lots of phone numbers and find them particularly recognizable.

Comment: @CarSmack, I didn't mean that he needs to change it to his exact real name.  I meant to change it to something humanly distinguishable.  Like, for example, "CarSmack".  And Cyberherbalist is very distinct.  I coined the term in my very first website (since taken by oversight by someone else) back in the mid-1990's or so.  My given name is so common it is anonymous.  My online persona is totally unique (so far).  Nobody else uses it (except the aforementioned website).  Go ahead, Google it.  Then compare what you get when you Google "Mike Clark".

Comment: "anonymous" usernames have been discussed on meta http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4057/users-whose-names-are-a-series-of-numbers-e-g-user-37562-does-elu-tell-users