# Is the term "Christian name" in decline in British English?

Tags: word-usage, british-english

I learned most of my British English as a lad of thirteen in 1968–69 and one of twenty in 1975–76, during which (academic) years I lived in Sussex. As a Yank (I think *that* at least is still a current usage, at least in schoolboy register), I then had to get used to the term *Christian name* for what I had always called simply my *first name.* As I approach my first visit to England in some sixteen years, I wonder if it is time to unlearn that lesson, what with the new London mayor and all. Does this usage garner odd looks in today’s more multicultural England? Will it perhaps mark the user as a UKIP (or, by transatlantic extension, Trump) sympathiser?

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Christian%20name&year_start=1968&year_end=2008&corpus=18&smoothing=3) suggests decline since 1968 but by no means to the point of vanishing. I can find no previous EL&U question on this, though there is some relevant discussion [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/217008/why-is-dolge-not-a-christian-name).

Comment: It would seem that way https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=christian+name%2Cfirst+name%2Cgiven+name&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=6&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cchristian%20name%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BChristian%20name%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bchristian%20name%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BChristian%20Name%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cfirst%20name%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bfirst%20name%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BFirst%20Name%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BFirst%20name%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cgiven%20name%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bgiven%20name%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BGiven%20name%3B%2Cc0

Comment: I certainly use the term *Christian name*, in referring to myself. And I believe many people of Anglo, European, or Caribbean descent (esp if they were over 50) would  use it, irrespective of whether they were churchgoers or atheists. But when it comes to Asian people, were I asking for their name, I might use *given name*. I wouldn't use *first name* and *last name* and I despair of it on forms. In many traditions, Chinese, Japanese, Indian, Arabic etc the family name goes first. So it can be very confusing. If we are going to standardise let's do it using *given name* and *family name*.

Comment: A lot of overseas Chinese (my wife is one), will adopt a western name in addition to their Chinese name. Especially this will be the case if they are Christian. Their "western" name will be their baptismal name - in the case of Roman Catholics, often a saint's name. So their passport identification will probably say *Michael Anthony Wong*, also known as *Wong Xi-Ping*.

Comment: Note that ngram results are not necessarily reliable. While its pre-20th-century corpus includes a lot of sermons, its more recent corpus includes an abundance of scientific literature. This would clearly affect how it registers a term like "Christian name" without telling us anything at all about how often everyday people use it. It is even possible that, in nonscientific lit, it is getting used more. (I'm not saying that it is, but, as far as one can glean from ngram, that is a real possibility.)

Comment: @surlawada - I had the same feeling on the corpus composition. I used ngram on the 2 French words: "[nom de baptême](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=nom+de+bapt%C3%AAme&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnom%20de%20bapt%C3%AAme%3B%2Cc0)" (baptismal or christian name)  and "[prénom](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pr%C3%A9nom&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpr%C3%A9nom%3B%2Cc0)" (given or first name). Surprisingly, both words show more and more occurences since 1960: conclusion?

Comment: As an aside, the implied equivalence between Trump and UKIP is pretty questionable, to say the least.

Comment: I am British, over 60, and often support UKIP.  These days, I generally use the term "first name", altho' I may also use "christian name".  I also wholly endorse the comment from @peterG: this forum is not an appropriate place for snide political comments!

Comment: @WS2 As regards the use of 'first name' in the context of Asian & other cultures, my general view is that this is an area where it has to be accepted that our usage & presentation of names is different from theirs: just as we would have to accept their usage & formatting when in their countries, do they have to accept ours when in our countries.  The same questions arise in relation to manners, customs, and many other cultural issues.

Comment: Similar issues also arise with the American usage of "middle name", especially with the increasing usage of online forms originating from US companies who do not know (or choose to ignore) that the UK has different customs in this area. I understand (but am willing to be corrected) that most Americans have one middle name.  OTOH, many UK people (albeit a minority) have no middle name, while other have multiple middle names. I have no middle name; my father-in-law had 3 middle names (yes, 5 names in total inc. first name & surname!).  How should we complete US forms asking for '"middle name"?

Comment: @WS2 What's your view on *surname* instead of *last name*?  As regards your suggestion of *given name*, how does that fit in with Am usage of 'first name' & 'middle name'; and with those who have multiple 'given names' (see my previous comment).  A separate issue is the accommodation of those people who are commonly known (especially among family and friends) by one of their 'middle names': I have a friend whose initials are RJSA ('A' refers to his surname), whose is generally known by the name "Jeremy" - his second name!

Comment: @TrevorD In a global market place, where "on-line" knows no national or cultural boundaries, I don't think we can retreat behind a screen of "if you don't like our customs take your business elsewhere*. If I am selling theatre seats, graduate courses, or life insurance policies, I don't care whether the customers are American, Chinese, Egyptian or Hindustani, as long as they pay me. So we need to design forms with customers in mind. And I think the terms *given name(s)* and *family name* are the way to go.

Comment: @WS2 But in what sequence do you then put the names? And what's your view on 'surname'?

Comment: @TrevorD If it was a form, and were it me designing it, I think I would use the time-honoured army method of surname first. But in a globalised world *surname* may not be universally understood. So I would go for *family name*.

Comment: @WS2, even *family name* (or *surname)* is an alien concept to Icelanders, who use given name and patronymic only. In my class lists, I alphabetize Icelanders by given name, though I  note with some astonishment that in the bibliography to Lee Hollander's otherwise learned edition/translation of *The Poetic Edda* Jóhann Hannesson, whom I knew, is listed and alphabetized as "Hannesson, Jóhann." When he was in America, admittedly, his wife and children adopted the patronymic "Hannesson" as if it had been a surname or family name.

Comment: @BrianDonovan well a *patronymic* is a kind of family name isn't it? If not, let's define *family name* to include *surnames* and *patronymics*. Do I understand that a patronymic is such that if you had a son, he wouldn't be Mr Donovan but Mr Brianson?

Comment: @WS2, Were we Icelanders, I think my son would be Mr. *Patrick* Brianson, and my daughter would be Ms. *Brigid* Briansdottir. (Rather Hibernian-sounding Icelanders, I grant you.) Courtesy title plus patronymic alone would seem fallacious in treating patronymic as more formal or fundamental than given name. I could even envision my daughter's being Dr. Brigid rather than Dr. Briansdottir. (Some of my colleagues in America affect "Dr." plus first name only, though that seems a little goofy to me.)

Comment: @BrianDonovan At my first place of work, a young office lady fell in love with a man whose surname name was *Bastard*. He asked her to marry him, but the poor child could not come to terms with having to be known by his surname, let alone the prospect of passing it on to any children she might bear. Her fiancée was equally perturbed about the thought of offending his father by changing it. Finally he agreed to change, but to his father's Christian name, plus son - so they became known as Mr & Mrs Frederickson. As far as I know they all lived happily ever after.

Comment: It appears from the [Ngram results for UK publications](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Christian+name%2Cgiven+name&year_start=1968&year_end=2008&corpus=18&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CChristian%20name%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgiven%20name%3B%2Cc0) that "given name" is taking up some of the slack from the gradual decline of "Christian name"—but something very strange happened in 1988.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The decrease in usage of the expression "Christian name" may be a reflection of the cultural changes that happen through time. It, however, didn't necessarily refer to religion, according to the following extract:

> - Traditionally, a christian name or baptismal name is a personal name given on the occasion of Christian baptism, with the ubiquity of infant baptism in medieval Christendom. ***In Elizabethan England, as suggested by Camden, the term christian name was not necessarily related to baptism, used merely in the sense of "given name":***
>
>   - "Christian names were imposed for the distinction of persons, surnames for the difference of families."
> - ***In more modern times, the terms have been used interchangeably with given name, first name and forename in traditionally Christian countries, and are still common in day-to-day use, although today, the secular term 'first name' is considerably the most common.***

(Wikipedia)

***[Usage notes](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Christian+name)***:

From The AHD:

> - Because it presupposes that an entire society is Christian, the term Christian name when used generically can be taken as offensive in diverse societies. Writers seeking a way to avoid this problem can use first name or forename instead.

From The Collins Dictionary:

> - Christian name was often loosely used to mean any person's first name as distinct from his or her surname. Nowadays, especially in official documents, alternatives which do not refer to a particular faith, and are therefore more inclusive, are often used: first name, forename, and given name.

Comment: What about people who originate from places where the family name goes first? What was *Mao Tse-Tung's* "first name"?

Comment: @WS2 - you want my personal view on this?

Comment: His first name was his familiy name: Mao. But someone asking for the first name likely means the part that isn't the family name.

Comment: @gnasher729 Which rather proves my point. The use of the terms *first name* and *last name* is just as problematic as *Christian name*.

Comment: @Josh61 My only point Josh is that which I have made in my comment to gnasher729, which is contrary to your quotation from *Collins*.I do not accept that *first name* is much more inclusive than *Christian name*. But your opinion would be of interest.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a Brit in my late 40s, so heading towards that *bah, in my day...* old fogey demographic that you mention (perish the thought).

I sometimes use "Christian name" out of sheer habit, but my (somewhat large) irreligious streak would prefer to use "forename" if my brain manages to engage quickly enough to overtake my mouth. "First name" is how it's increasingly used on official forms, however, such as Government documents - I just checked my self-assessment return, and it's clearly labelled *First Name/Middle Name/Last Name*.

As for "Yank" - yeah, that'll work, though you can also use *'merkin* or *left-ponder* if you want to confuse people :)

Comment: Because *merkin* means pubic wig, any use of that will have a particular, possibly undesirable, flavor.

Comment: {whistles innocently}