# As family name unambiguous defines surname versus last name what name should be used for social friendly name

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, names

In many parts of the world the sequence of first name and surname is not always the same and can cause misunderstanding what should be given.

As family name unambiguous defines surname or last name what name should be used for the name used for you as your social friendly name.

Options:

- first name,
- call name,
- Christian name
- baptism name
- baptismal name
- forename

What should be used as an unambiguous name.

Comment: It can be a problem.  The only answer is to ask the person what to call her/him and do that.

Comment: The question is to improve forms and other documents that can be used without to create  misunderstanding what should be filled in, Family name does that but that other name is vague.

Comment: In some cultures all the names a person has are 'given names'. In other words there is no surname. Some young Muslim ladies in the UK use Begum as a surname but this is, I understand, Arabic for 'young female person' and hardly even a name in the culture from which they come.

Comment: Strongly relevant and related: [1](https://shinesolutions.com/2018/01/08/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names-with-examples/), [2](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22christian+name%22), [3](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-personal-names).

Comment: Please see the referenced related links, and then if you still have a specific question about a specific use in a specific region for a specific set of cultural names, please edit your question to specify your question, including which terms your research discarded and why, and it will be automatically nominated for reöpening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s common to refer to a two-part name as consisting of a **family name** and a **given name**:

> A name given to a person at birth or at baptism, as distinguished from a surname.

([American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=given%20name))

Comment: [Sure hope the OP isn't looking for a term to use here on a paper form or in a program](https://shinesolutions.com/2018/01/08/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names-with-examples/). :)

Comment: I marked this as the best answer. For "Given name" I also explain that it is the name one got from the parents a birth. For "Family name" I explain that it is an inherent name.

Answer (score 2):

Talking about what is common in North American English (this actually differs a bit with British English usage):

Certainly **Christian name** and **baptismal name** make a lot of cultural assumptions that do not apply to everyone - not everyone is Christian or has been baptized.

Furthermore, even **first name** does not equal "social friendly name" for everyone.  Some people prefer a shortened nickname ("Bob" for "Robert") or a nickname that's unrelated to their first name ("Junior" for someone with the same name as their father).  I, personally, use a shortened version my middle name as my "social friendly name" rather than my first name.

Many human resources databases use the term **preferred name** to indicate the name taht someone wants people to address them with.  So you might see an entry like this:

> **First name:** Rafael
>
> **Last name:** Cruz
>
> **Preferred name:** Ted

Given that data, formal documents (e.g., tax receipts) would get the first and last name ("Rafael Cruz") but informal emails would get the preferred name (e.g., "Hey Ted, welcome to the team!").

Comment: This may come as a surprise, but please understand that your "Christian name" no more means you're a follower of Christ than "walking Indian file" or "sitting Indian style" means you’re an Indian. Similarly "going Dutch" does ɴᴏᴛ mean you're dating a Nederlander, and playing "Chinese checkers" does ɴᴏᴛ mean that game ever had anything to do with China. These things happen in all languages; for example in Spanish, *hablar cristiano* does ɴᴏᴛ mean to speak Christian: it means to speak properly. Your *Christian name* is your given name no matter your avowed religion or lack of same.

Comment: @tchrist - I know that "Christian name" might be common in the UK, but in North America it's decidedly not common at all and would be extremely strange and possibly offensive in a formal situation. This was discussed a bit in an [older post](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/324979/is-the-term-christian-name-in-decline-in-british-english).

Comment: @tchrist - I'm editing my answer to make it clear that I'm talking specifically about North American usage.

Comment: ‡ Thank you for curating your answer.

Comment: @tchrist - In my youth _Christian name_ was the usual term in the UK, dating from the time when everyone was baptised as a matter of course. We don't use the term any more, since large sections of our population are of other faiths.

Comment: @KateBunting Have you switched to Rutabagas yet, or are you still chewing on Swedes? I mean, you know more Swedish people now, surely, so it seems abusive to stew them. :)

Comment: "first and last name" - Many cultures starts with the family name as first followed by other names and the last name can evenbe a call name as "Ted".

Comment: @janhgm - And other cultures do not use a "family name"  handed down from their parents at all. The only truly culturally neutral thing you can do is not force people to split up their name and to have a single field called **full name** where they can type the entire thing.

Comment: @Canadian Yankee - So what do you suggest to make it easy to get one people names in an IT system and later to be able to use different styles of addressing. Till now the best suggestion I have is using family name, given name and preferred name.